# How do I make an SQL statement to return all rows when a variable is blank, otherwise return only matches

Tags: sql, mysql

How do I use an SQL statement to return all rows if the input parameter is empty, otherwise only return rows that match?

My SQL looks like this

```
where person.personstatusuid = @StatusUID
           AND person.forename != ''
           AND person.location = @Location
```

but I want basically, person.location = @Location  OR  @Location is blank

How do I do it? Using CASE WHEN perhaps...

Answer (score 2):

Just use OR?

```
where person.personstatusuid = @StatusUID
AND person.forename != ''
AND (person.location = @Location or IsNull(@location,'')='')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   person.personstatusuid = @StatusUID
        AND person.forename != ''
        AND person.location = @Location
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   person.personstatusuid = @StatusUID
        AND person.forename != ''
        AND @Location IS NULL
```

This solution, unlike using `OR`, is index friendly: it will optimize away the redundant `SELECT` and use the index.

See this article in my blog for a similar problem with performance details:

- [**Selecting options**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/26/selecting-options/)

(this is for `MySQL`, but applicable to `SQL Server` just as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple OR condition:

```
where person.personstatusuid = @StatusUID
           AND person.forename != ''
           AND (person.location = @Location OR @Location IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

If person.location doesn't allow nulls the following will work too...

```
where person.personstatusuid = @StatusUID
AND person.forename != ''
AND person.location = isnull(@Location,person.location)
```

This assumes if all rows are required then @Location is passed as null and not an empty string ('')